# Embed youtube in ios 9

Tags: xcode, youtube, embed, ios9

I've embeded youtube videos in ios 8 many times using the following code (I intentionally replace the video code with ----). After upgrading to ios 9, the video no longer plays (go to a YouTube Help page title "Video player error message".

Does anyone know what changed in ios 9 and how to fix this?

```
NSString *EmbedCode = @"<iframe width=\"560\" height=\"315\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/-------\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";
[[self webviewer] loadHTMLString:EmbedCode baseURL:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

In iOS9 it is important to switch everything to HTTPS.

So I'm facing the same problems like you. Some videos are playing, some videos are not playing.

See [Apple’s App Transport Security Technote](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/index.html) for full details

(Source: WWDC 2015 session 703, “Privacy and Your App”, 30:18)

You can also ignore all app transport security restrictions with a single key:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

With adding the key everything works. But I think this is only a temporary solution. You don't know when apple starts rejecting this.

I also filed an issue at Google.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, but in the last few days, it has started to work on iOS 9 with no security exemptions. I think Google got their servers up to the required security levels.